# Selenium, Too many "divs" to select Cant select....(Beginner) (I Give up)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Too many divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhzr2.png)

how to select this...

Comment: How would you describe the location in english (or other spoken language)? I find this is a good starting point. ex: "The 4th div", "The last input in the group", "The svg under the div with a class called 'jitsi-icon'". After you figure that out, then try and translate it to XPath or CSS selector terms.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Provide more details on which element are you trying to select. As let us know what all have you tried. Also go through this link on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). With just 2 word question is not enough as a description.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath :

```
//*[local-name() = 'svg']
```

Comment: HI there, I am too noob using selenium..... i didnt understand what is "local name"

Comment: check this link ::https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-in-scope-prefixes